Oracle Package Compilation Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the Symbol "end-of-file" When Expecting ";"
I am encountering an issue while creating an Oracle package in my APEX application. The package compiles successfully in another environment, but in my current environment, I receive the following error:
Error at line 22: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
Here is the code for the package:

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ul_sync_pkg AS 

    FUNCTION get_version RETURN VARCHAR2;

    TYPE environments_tbl IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 

    PROCEDURE context_topic(
        p_context_id_i   IN ul_context.context_id%TYPE,
        p_source_env_i   IN ul_environment.env_name%TYPE,
        p_target_envs_i  IN environments_tbl,
        p_message_o      OUT VARCHAR2
    );

    PROCEDURE sync_alias(
        p_context_id_i   IN ul_context.context_id%TYPE,
        p_source_env_i   IN ul_environment.env_name%TYPE,
        p_target_envs_i  IN environments_tbl,
        p_message_o      OUT VARCHAR2
    );

    FUNCTION get_system_user RETURN NUMBER;

    FUNCTION get_apex_user RETURN NUMBER;

END ul_sync_pkg;
/


When I remove the TYPE environments_tbl IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; line, the package compiles without any errors. However, I need this type definition in the package.
Steps I've Taken:
Verified that the database version and configurations are the same between environments.
Ensured that all dependent objects (ul_context and ul_environment) are present and correctly defined.
Checked for hidden or non-printable characters in the script.
Tried different PL/SQL editors and SQL tools (SQL Developer, SQL*Plus)
The same code works in another environment.
The issue seems specifically related to the TYPE environments_tbl IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; line since when I am removing above line and it's references then code is not giving any syntax error.
Note: Previously same code was working fine in same env.

Your code works without errors fiddle

Are you sure you have the / at the end of the version you are running? You'd get that error without that - though at line 25, not 22.

True, it fails (I have no idea why) if you run it as a SQL Command.
However, if you save that code as a script and run it, package gets created.








